# Unable to access localhost using my ip address into another pc

Tags: c#

I published my web .net application on local server, and running it to on my pc's browser with some querystring values then its working properly, but when running it to from other local pc which is connected with network not working ..

in page load i am counting parameters and checking it to some const value then entering to some action codes, else displaying error msg like 'please provide values'. so whenever i am browsing 'http://192.168.1.22:8091/UserPayment.aspx?OID=1024&MID=10&CID=102&UID=92&PAMT=50&TOT=03082015142000&CPHNO=9000959239&RCPT=1024&CHKNUM=0&TT=2'

thowing an error : The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Receive_Payment_CompanyRegistered". The conflict occurred in database "crm", table "dbo.CompanyRegistered", column 'Comp_Id'. The statement has been terminated. where as after debugg application directly not throwing any error its excecuting and inserting record sucessfully.

```
    String urlString = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri).OriginalString;
    var queryParameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new Uri(urlString).Query);
    var numberOfParameter = queryParameters.Count;
    if (numberOfParameter == 10)
     {
      int OrranizationID = 0, MachineID = 0, empId = 0, customerId = 0;
      string PhoneNo = Request.QueryString["CPHNO"] == null ? "0" : Request.QueryString["CPHNO"].ToString();
      string RecieptNo = Request.QueryString["RCPT"] == null ? "0" : Request.QueryString["RCPT"].ToString();
      string ChequeNo = Request.QueryString["CHQNUM"] == null ? "0" : Request.QueryString["CHQNUM"].ToString();
      string PaidAmnt = Request.QueryString["PAMT"] == null ? "0" : Request.QueryString["PAMT"].ToString();
      string TransactionTime = Request.QueryString["TOT"] == null ? "0" : Request.QueryString["TOT"].ToString();
    OrranizationID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["OID"] == null ? "0" : Request.QueryString["OID"].ToString());
    MachineID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["MID"] == null ? "0" : Request.QueryString["MID"].ToString());
    empId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["UID"] == null ? "0" : Request.QueryString["UID"].ToString());
     customerId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["CID"] == null ? "0" : Request.QueryString["CID"].ToString());
}


    else
       {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please provide PaymentInfo');", true);    
       }
```

Comment: Just FYI, you can simplify your code by doing this: `string PhoneNo = Request.QueryString["CPHNO"] ?? "0";`. The `ToString()` is not necessary, and that lets you use the null-coalescing operator.

Comment: That's a completely different topic. That error is because you are inserting a value with a foreign key that does not exist. We gave no information about your tables so it's not easy to help you, but my guess is that this incorrect value is in the field `Comp_Id` in table `Receive_Payment`, and that value is missing in table `CompanyRegistered`.

Answer (score 0):

Disable (temporarily) windows firewall and other firewall/antivirus software that may affect the inbound connections. Make sure the website binding is eithery any IP, or your actual local ip (not 127.0.0.1).

Comment: thowing an error : The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Receive_Payment_CompanyRegistered". The conflict occurred in database "crm", table "dbo.CompanyRegistered", column 'Comp_Id'. The statement has been terminated. where as after debugg application directly not throwing any error its excecuting and inserting record sucessfully.

Comment: Your original question was different, you should not edit it that much.
Anyway, my guess would be that you have different databases when deployed and when running debug.

Comment: yes because that time I was catching error throw Registerscripmanager alert popup so that was not displayed, so now i catching throw hidden label then get this msg.

Comment: and databases not different both are same..which database i am using in sql same as it is using for iis too.

Answer (score 0):

that is windows firewall problem.

kindly turnoff your windows firewall on application hosted pc.

if you don't want turnoff firewall please follow below step

• Go to Control Panel.

• Go to Windows Firewall.

• Go to advance Setting.

• Go to Inbound Rules (Left side panel).

• Click on New Rules (Right side panel).

• Step 1 Rule Type : Select Port

• Step 2 Protocol and Ports : Select TCP and select specific local port and enter your application's port number.

• Step 3 Action : Select Allow the Connection.

• Step 4 Profile : Select all checkbox Domain, Private, Public.

• Step 5 Name : Enter Name as you want.

Comment: Please turn off firewall temporary and also turnoff anti-virus and try if it work let me know i will give you full description. and if it will not work when firewall is off than problem is another.

Comment: then also not working after publish but working after application debug.

Comment: thowing an error : The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Receive_Payment_CompanyRegistered". The conflict occurred in database "crm", table "dbo.CompanyRegistered", column 'Comp_Id'. The statement has been terminated. where as after debugg application directly not throwing any error its excecuting and inserting record sucessfully.